# django-tz-detect automatically save timezone to user model

Tags: django, timezone, middleware

I want to automatically save a user's timezone to their profile after it has been detected by the django-tz-detect package.

Use case: I have a simple app that allows users to sign up and reserve time slots.

Features:

- As little overhead as possible for users. Simply sign up with a name and email address, then click a button to reserve a time slot.
- Admin user can send email reminders to users when their time slots are approaching.

Problem: The email sent to users is not formatted by their local time zone, as django-tz-detect is only concerned with the current timezone of that session.

How can I format times in the user's local timezone in the reminder email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished with simple custom middleware.

Make sure you're using django-tz-detect.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    'tz_detect',
    'myapp.apps.MyappConfig',
]
```

Add your own middleware to the stack, after django-tz-detect.

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    # ...
    'tz_detect.middleware.TimezoneMiddleware',
    'myapp.middleware.UserTimezoneMiddleware',
]
```

myapp/middleware.py

```
from django.utils import timezone

class UserTimezoneMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)

        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            if request.session.get('detected_tz'): # (set by django-tz-detect)
                tz = timezone.get_current_timezone()
                if tz:
                    tz = str(tz)
                    # (this assumes your user model has a char field called "timezone")
                    if tz != request.user.timezone:
                        request.user.timezone = tz
                        request.user.save()

        return response
```

Timezone strings (e.g. "America/Chicago") are now automatically saved to the user model, and updated if the user logs in from a different tz.